# If the function f is defined as a set of ordered pairs that fullfill certain criteria, then how can I define f(x)?

Tags: functions, set-theory, definition, relations

Assume that $f=\{(x,y)|Pxy\}$ is a function.

My best attempts so far include the following:

1. $f(x)=y \iff (x,y)\in f$

The problem with this method is that I still don't have a standalone definition for f(x). Say, if I'm given f(x) in a random formula, like f(x)*2-3, I'm still unsure about how to "replace" f(x) in terms of f.

2. $f(x)=\{y|(x,y)\in f\}$

This definition solves the previous problem, in that I can switch between the f(x) and RHS whenever I like without needing f(x) to be equal to a preexisting/predefined variable in order to do so. But the problem is, this definition of f(x), rigorously speaking, does not return the value I am looking for. Rather, it returns a SET that contains the only value that I am looking for. Unless there exists a notation that takes the only element out of a set, I can't make use of this definition either...

Consider the following example. I am given that:

$f=\{(x,y)|x\in\mathbb{R}\land y\in \mathbb{R}\ \land y+x=5\}$

After rearranging the expression and moving y to LHS:

$f=\{(x,y)|x\in \mathbb{R} \land y\in \mathbb{R} \land y=5-x\}$

How can I show, using some definition of f(x), that $x\in \mathbb{R} \implies f(x)=5-x$?

Or maybe to simplify the above example, assume that everything is a real number and

$f=\{(x,y)|y=5-x\}$

What definition of f(x) can I use that would give me $f(x)=5-x$?

Comment: One approach is to say that $f(x)$ is just a shorthand for $\bigcup \{y: (x, y) \in f\}$, if you are happy to accept that "taking the union" is a valid operation. Alternatively, if $P(f(x))$ is a statement you wish to make involving $f(x)$, you can define this to be $(\forall y)((x, y) \in f \implies P(y))$. Honestly I think the real answer is that you probably shouldn't get too hung up on this - it's not very important to rigorously define $f(x)$ because everyone knows what it means. But it can certainly be fun to think about how things formalise in foundations if you're into that!

Comment: "Assume that $f=\{(x,y)|Pxy\}$ is a function." -- What's your definition of a function?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe according to my definition, f is a function from A to B, if and only if, $f\in A\times B \land \forall x\in A\exists! y\in B:(x,y)\in f$

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen could you provide me with a link about "taking the union"? From my current understanding of union of sets, the union of sets still returns a set, not an element...

Comment: In set theory, all the elements of a set are sets! Working backwards, we know $\{y: (x, y) \in f\}$ is $\{f(x)\}$. Taking a union over this set "flattens" it, and gives us $f(x)$. The notation $\bigcup \mathcal A$ means the same as $\bigcup_{A \in \mathcal A} A$ - it's "the union of all sets belonging to $\mathcal A$". Can you convince yourself that $\bigcup \{\{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}, \{\emptyset, \emptyset\}\}\} = \{\emptyset, \{\emptyset\}, \{\emptyset, \emptyset\}\}$? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_(set_theory)#Notations, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_union.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ is a function, then $(x,y),(x,y')\in f\implies y=y'$ i.e. there can only be one output for a single input $x$. (Moreover, for each $x$ in the domain, $\exists y:(x,y)\in f$ i.e. there is at least one output for every input $x$, and hence exactly one output.)

Thus, $f(x)=y$ iff $(x,y)\in f$ is exactly the definition we take, and it is unambiguous: it equates $f(x)$ with exactly one value, the unique value $y$ such that $(x,y)\in f$.

---

In (2), your set $\{y|(x,y)\in f\}$ is a singleton for each input $x$ in the domain of $f$ (and empty for other $x$). $\{y\}$ is not the same as $y$, so we cannot define $f(x)$ this way, but you could define it by $f(x)=a\iff a\in \{y|(x,y)\in f\}$. However, this is just the first definition with extra complications, as $a\in \{y|(x,y)\in f\}\iff (x,a)\in f$.

---

If you want to derive a "proof" that $f=\{(x,y)|x\in R\ \text{and}\ y\in R\ \text{and}\ y=5-x\}$ and $x\in R$ implies $f(x)=5-x$, you need set theory and logic:

$$\begin{align} f(x)=y&\iff (x,y)\in f\\ &\iff (x,y)\in \{(x,y)|x\in R\ \text{and}\ y\in R\ \text{and}\ y=5-x\}\\ &\iff y\in R\ \text{and}\ y=5-x\end{align}$$ (the last step is because $x\in R$).

This is as far as we can go, because you also need the condition $5-x\in R$ in order for $f(x)=y$ to be true, in your definition of $f$. For instance, if $R$ is the set of real numbers, $\mathbb{R}$, then this is always true (i.e. $x\in \mathbb{R}\implies 5-x\in\mathbb{R}$). But if $R$ is the set of all positive integers then this is not true e.g. $x=2\implies 5-x\not\in R$ (because the number $-3$ doesn't exist in this set).

There is no reason you have to take $x\in R$ and $y\in R$ as your conditions, though, as functions often have different domains and ranges. So you might like to say $y\in S$ and then we have $x\in R\ \text{and}\ 5-x\in S\implies f(x)=5-x$, which is the minimum set of premises required to reach this conclusion.

Comment: I meant for R to be the set of real numbers, but didn't know how to input the symbol the exact symbol, and I felt like the question was already too long for me to be adding small details like this. Sorry for the ambinguity in my question.

Comment: @DarkRebellion I see - I think my comment should still make sense and answer your question (if you are using $\mathbb{R}$ then you need a proof that $x\in\mathbb{R}\implies 5-x\in\mathbb{R}$, from whatever definition of $\mathbb{R}$ you have).

Comment: Your comment did indeed still make sense, I just felt bad for making you put in more effort than I required!

Comment: I have one more question... In the last example, we are able to show that $y=5-x \iff f(x)=y$ (assuming real numbers, so no problems with the domains). I am still unsure how to proceed from here in order to show that f(x)=5-x...

Comment: @DarkRebellion Double implication is stronger than single implication, so we conclude $f(x)=y\implies y=5-x$ and thus $f(x)=y=5-x$ and $f(x)=5-x$ (as $=$ is transitive).